# Count records this month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores dates in the format of MM/DD/YY (field name is date). I need to have a count that totals just the records for the current month. From searching, this is what I currently have but something is not right. Do I need to do a convertToDate, is it that my field is called "date", or am I missing something entirely?

```
$totalcount = mysql_query("select count(*) as 'total' 
                           FROM state_to_state 
                           WHERE status = 99 AND type = 1 
                           AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
                           AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURDATE())");

$totalnum = mysql_fetch_array($totalcount);
if($totalnum['total'] > 0) { $month_status = $totalnum['total']." this Month. "; }
```

Comment: looks ok, `date` is a date type?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: If the field is stored in the format `mm/dd/yy` then it's not a `date` type. MySQL expects dates to be `yyyy-mm-dd`. Are you really using 2-digit years, have you forgotten Y2K?

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are NOT native mysql dates (varchar, probably?), so you cannot use the mysql date functions on them directly. `date('MM/DD/YY')` will not work reliably:

```
mysql> select month('03/03/14'), month('03/18/14');
+-------------------+-------------------+
| month('03/03/14') | month('03/18/14') |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|                 3 |              NULL |
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Convert your date fields to native mysql date types, or take a huge hit on performance and convert them to native date values onthefly via [str_to_date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: You're right, it is a varchar. At the time the only reason date was needed was for user convenience - really nothing more. I'll do as you suggest and convert all to native mysql date types and change everything moving forward. Thanks!